# DSA vs RSA: how can you tell

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

Does anyone have a tool to use in order to differentiate an RSA public key vs a DSA public key?  I have two SSH .pub files and i need to know if they're RSA or DSA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the other answer, since the file is in SSH.COM format, you can convert to openssh format and just open the file to check for `ssh-dsa` or `ssh-rsa`:

```
To convert your SSH.COM key to OpenSSH format use:

ssh-keygen -i -f ssh_key.pub

From the ssh-keygen manpage

 -i   This option will read an unencrypted private (or public) key
      file in SSH2-compatible format and print an OpenSSH
      compatible private (or public) key to stdout.  ssh-keygen
      also reads the `SECSH Public Key File Format'.  This option
      allows importing keys from several commercial SSH
      implementations.
 -f  Specifies the filename of the key file.
```

Source: http://landru.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?OpenSSH_-_SSH.Com_Interoperability

Answer (score 2):

You can use ssh-keygen to get a fingerprint and type out of a .pub file:

```
ssh-keygen -lf id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. OP asks how to know if a key is created with DSA or RSA. This command shows exactly that. For example it shows something like this:
2048 SHA256:AfgaWZ5.... cmk@cms (RSA)